# Filtering jQuery Results by CSS Tag

Tags: jquery, optimization

I am trying to **dynamically** filter search results. Every result has tags associated with it that are used as classes.

```
<div class="search_results">
    <div class="html php jquery">
        I can do HTML, PHP and JQuery.
    </div>

    <div class="jquery asp pascal">
        I can do jQuery, ASP, and Pascal.
    </div>

    <div class="php basic webOS">
        I am a PHP, Visual Basic, and WebOS expert.
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to dynamically select results based on tag.  I understand how to do this statically:

```
/* Hide all search results */
jQuery(".search_results div").hide(); 

/* Show everything with .php and .jquery tags */
jQuery(".search_results .php, .search_results .jquery").show()
```

However, I need this to happen dynamically based upon a list of checked boxes.

```
<div class="filters">
    <input type="checkbox" value="php" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="jquery" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="webOS" />
    etc..
</div>
```

When those boxes are checked, I want to filter my results.

My Question: What function would I use to do this?  Every page result has different collection of tags.  Would it be something like this?

```
// Create new array
var filter_array = new Array();

// wait for a filter checkbox to be clicked
jQuery(".filters input").click(function() {

    // Cycle through all input fields, and focus only on checked ones
    jQuery('.filters input:checked').each( function() {

        // Add current value to array
        filter_array.push(jQuery(this).val());

    });

    // Now filter the results
    for(i=0; i< filter_array.length;i++) {

        // Hide all results
        jQuery(".search_results div").hide(); /* Hide all search results */

        // What do I do here to make sure elements that are dipslayed meet all the filter criteria?

    }

});
```

Also, do I have to use the loop function? Is there a way to do this faster?  Suppose I could have as many as 50-100 result elements on one page.  I am not very familiar with jQuery optimization, so I am trying to find the most efficient way of doing this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
jQuery('.filters input:checked').each( function() {

    // Add current value to array
    filter_array.push(jQuery(this).val());

});

jQuery(".search_results div").hide().filter('.' + filter_array.join(',.')).show();
```

This constructs a string like `.jquery,.php,.python` and then shows the `div`s matching that all-in-one selector.  (Note that we've already limited the selection to `.search_results div` so we don't need to traverse the document more than once looking for those.)